# Excel formula to Concatenate multiple values from columns based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to concatenate values (header + value) from about 150 columns.

This is the formula that I used:
`=IF(B2<>0,$B$1&": "&B2,"")&" " &IF(C2<>0,$C$1&": "&C2,"")`
This is just an example and it just concatenates values from two columns.

Do you have any ideas how to write the formula so that it concatenates values from 150 columns easily - based on my criteria, which is: value <> 0.

This is just a sample data:

[image]

Comment: What version of Excel have you got? You'd want to use the `TEXTJOIN()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As JvdV suggested, if you have `TEXTJOIN()` formula then could try-

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF(B2:E2<>0,$B$1:$E$1 & ":" & B2:E2,""))
```

You may need to array entry for non-365 version of excel. Array entry means put formula to cell then press `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

[image]